# Filter array of elements with duplicate value, choose the one with a specific value in another property

Tags: javascript

The situation is that I have an array of some objects, let's call them events.

Each event has a "name" and a "type" property. I want to filter out events that have the same "name" by keeping those that have a specific "type". I do not want to filter out events that have no duplicates!
Basically the concept is to end up with a list of distinctly named events where wherever there was a duplicate NAME the event with the given TYPE was kept in the array.

How can I do that? I know I can use events.filter() to simply remove duplicates but how do I choose depending on another column?

Sample:

```
var eventArray = [{name:"test",type:"building"}, {name:"test",type:"learning"}, 
                  {name:"audit", type:"preparing"}, {name:"audit", type:"learning"},
{name:"bla",type:"blue"}];
```

My goal is to filter out events with duplicate names but during this filtering, to keep the ones with type "learning". So the end result should be:

```
var eventArray = [{name:"test",type:"learning"},  {name:"audit", type:"learning"},{name:"bla",type:"blue"}];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some more inputs and their expected outputs that cover all boundary cases? Also share your attempt.

Comment: See my edit, does that help?

Comment: Nope, share more inputs and outputs along with what you have tried.

Comment: You question is really unclear,you can just show us the input and expected output and what you have tried.

Comment: Guys the question is not so unclear. I tried to edit again, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a first version, the first function (duplicateNames) will return an array of duplicated name values in the event array. The removeDuplicated method, checks if a name is duplicated, if it is, it will only grab the one with the preferred type, if it's not duplicated, it will simply add it.

There is a drawback to this though, if you have a duplicated name, but none of the objects are of the preferred type, they will be ignored, e.g.:

```
var eventArray = [{name: 'test', type: 'hello'}, {name: 'test', type: 'hello2'}];
```

Also, if the type is also duplicated, you will get two entries, is this what you'd expect?

```js
const eventArray = [
 {name:"test5",type:"building"},
 {name:"test5",type:"building"},
 {name:"test",type:"building"},
 {name:"test",type:"learning"},
 {name:"audit", type:"preparing"},
 {name:"audit", type:"learning"}
];

function uniq(array) {
 return array
  .map(item => JSON.stringify(item))
  .filter((item, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === index)
  .map(item => JSON.parse(item));
}

function duplicatedNames(array) {
 const names = array.map(item => item.name);
 return names
  .filter((name, index) => names.indexOf(name) !== index);
}


function removeDuplicates(array, preferenceType) {
 const unique = uniq(array);
 const duplicated = duplicatedNames(unique);
 const result = [];

 for (const item of unique) {
  if (duplicated.indexOf(item.name) >= 0 && item.type === preferenceType) {
   result.push(item);
  } else if (duplicated.indexOf(item.name) < 0) {
   result.push(item);
  }
 }

 return result;
}

console.log(removeDuplicates(eventArray, 'learning'));
```

Comment: When the name is duplicated, not all properties

Comment: Also the thing is, that it's possible to have events without this type and then I don't want them removed. I want them removed only when there are duplicate names!

Comment: @jimmious And so, if the name is duplicated, you want to only keep the one matching the given type I assume? So in essence, you want an array of the duplicated items that match the given type?

Comment: No wait, I got you wrong. I want an array of distinctly named items. If there were items with the same name, I want to "keep" the ones with the preferred type! Let's assume that the type can only have 2 different values

Comment: Makes sense, but, what would you want to do with duplicated items that don't match the preferred type, and duplicated name items that also have duplicated types? I've added a sample for the first case.

Comment: In theory so far I can have only 2 types and an event can't have twice the same type in an array, so the first issue is (probably) not applicable.
For complete duplicates I guess keeping one is fine :)

Comment: Thanks Gorka, it worked fine with a bit of tinkering (to fit my specific data)!!

Comment: @jimmious That's great to hear, just in case, I added a duplicated record that filters the array for complete duplicates (by turning the objects into strings first and parsing them before the output). That way you should not get any complete duplicates in the output.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#filter` to filter out your array based on a condition. Then, use `array#reduce` to uniquely group result based on `name` and store it in an object. Then extract out all the values from this object using `Object.values()`.

```js
var eventArray = [{name:"test",type:"building"}, {name:"test",type:"learning"},{name:"audit", type:"preparing"}, {name:"audit", type:"learning"}, {name:"audit", type:"learning"}, {name:"audit", type:"learning"}],
    result = Object.values(eventArray.filter(({type}) => type === 'learning').reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.name] = o;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't try out your answer due to the answer of Gorka working for me :)